# apex:selectList value returning null to controller using onchange

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

I'm having some problems to get apex:selectList value in controller. When I choose the value, I receive "Attempt to de-reference a null object". Am I missing something here? Can you help me?

**Visualforce code**

```
<apex:outputpanel id="AListPanelInstallation">
  <apex:selectList id="selectAListInstallation" styleClass="selectAClass" size="1" value="{!selectedA}" disabled="{!!enableModals}" multiselect="false">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!AList}"/>
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateModalList}" reRender="modalListInstallation" /> <!-- I've tried actionSupport before and after selectOptions -->
  </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

**Controller**

```
public void updateModalList(){
    List<FSINT_Brazil_TMP_ServiceModel.Modals> updatedModalList = dspIdModalListMap.get(selectedA);
    if(!modalList.isEmpty()){
        modalList.clear();
    }
    modalList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf('Default'), 'Select model'));
    if(selectedA<>'Default'){ 
        for(FSINT_Brazil_TMP_ServiceModel.Modals updatedModal_aux : updatedModalList){
            String modalToDisplay = String.valueOf(updatedModal_aux.unitValue)+' ('+String.valueOf(updatedModal_aux.service)+')';
            modalList.add(new SelectOption(updatedModal_aux.code, modalToDisplay));
        }
        
        Map<String, Integer> dspIdSLAMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for(FSINT_Brazil_TMP_ServiceModel.ServiceProvider serviceProvider_aux : deliveryProviderModalsListMap.keySet()){
            dspIdSLAMap.put(serviceProvider_aux.Id, serviceProvider_aux.sla);
        }
        if(dspIdSLAMap.get(selectedA)<>null){
            selectedASLA = dspIdSLAMap.get(selectedA);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` calls JavaScript; you need to use `apex:actionSupport`.

Apex methods are called with `{!method}` syntax in an `action` attribute, while the "on*event*" methods (e.g. `onchange`) call JavaScript methods using normal JavaScript syntax.

Do not return `PageRereference` from an action method unless you intend to redirect. This makes it clearer that you have no intent to move to a new page as a result of calling this action.`

`get` methods in Apex become [getters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm) in Visualforce. You generally don't want to do that without considering possible side effects.

> It’s a best practice for getter methods to be idempotent, that is, to not have side effects. For example, don’t increment a variable, write a log message, or add a new record to the database. Visualforce doesn’t define the order in which getter methods are called, or how many times they might be called in the course of processing a request. Design your getter methods to produce the same outcome, whether they are called once or multiple times for a single page request.

Your code should look more like this:

```
<apex:selectList id="selectAList" styleClass="selectAClass" size="1" value="{!selectedA}" disabled="{!!enableModals}">
  <apex:actionSupport event="change" action="{!updateModalList}" reRender="form" />
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!AList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

---

```
public void updateModalList(){ 
    System.debug(':::selectedA::: ' +selectedA); *//printing null***
    List<FSINT_Brazil_TMP_ServiceModel.Modals> updatedModalList = dspIdModalListMap.get(selectedA);
    modalList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf('Default'), 'Select'));
    if(selectedA<>'Default'){
        for(FSINT_Brazil_TMP_ServiceModel.Modals updatedModal_aux : updatedModalList){
            String modalToDisplay = String.valueOf(updatedModal_aux.unitValue)+' ('+String.valueOf(updatedModal_aux.service)+')';
            modalList.add(new SelectOption(updatedModal_aux.code, modalToDisplay));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried <apex:actionSupport event="change" action="{!updateModalList}" reRender="form" /> but updateModalList is not even called in controller. So I've tried event="onchange" at actionSupport and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @SabrinaT. Can you edit your question to include the new code? You're right, it should have been `onchange` instead of just `change`, but that should have fixed it, I would have thought.

Comment: I edited the code